# C# cast from child with more specific generic to parent with less specific generic

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, covariance, contravariance

I am trying to cast from a child with a specific generic to a parent with a more general generic.

Take the following code:

```cs
public class AParent { }
public class AChild : AParent { }

public interface IParent<T>
{
    public void func(T input);
}

public class Child : IParent<AChild>
{
    public void func(AChild input) { }
}

public static void test()
{
    IParent<AParent> parent = new Child();
}
```

In this code, I have `AParent` and `AChild` where `AChild` inherits from `AParent`.

I also have `IParent` which takes in a generic type parameter and `Child` which inherits from `IParent` with a specific type of `AChild`.

I feel like this should work logically? But I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Child' to 'IParent<AParent>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I've also tried adding the `in`/`out` keyword to the `T` type parameter on `IParent` but to no avail. Is what I'm trying to do possible? It seems logical, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is a simple answer and I just need an explicit cast

Comment: No, the explicit cast can only succeed if someone has written a class that implements _both_ `IParent<AChild>` _and_ `IParent<AParent>` which is not the case here.

Comment: `Child.func()` expects an instance of `AChild`. You can't cast an instance of `AParent` to a variable of `AChild`. Which means you can't cast the function, nor the interface. As this would allow you to break .net's type safety.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You're right. Thanks for pointing that out, that seems to be the piece I've overlooked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This generic interface:

```cs
public interface IParent<T>
{
    public void func(T input);
}
```

The type parameter `T` is used only as "input". So it would be legal to declare this a *contravariant* interface, like this:

```cs
public interface IParent<in T>
{
    public void func(T input);
}
```

This allows the opposite conversion of what you want:

```cs
IParent<AGrandchild> parent = new Child();
```

where `AGrandchild` is a class inheriting `AChild`.

---

Making the interface *covariant* ("`out`") would not be sound when there is an "in" use of `T`.